# XIB view doesn't show anything despite being correctly initialized

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xib

I'm trying to use a .xib file to make a reusable view inside a TableViewCell. I give all the data needed to the TableViewCell which has an UIView which is my reusable .xib. I correctly print the init functions in the UIView but nothing shows in the simulator screen. Can't find why and I'm stuck for a long time now.

Here is my xib file:
[image]

Which is correctly associated with my UIView:

```
import Kingfisher

class DebateBoxView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var debateBoxView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var debateBoxImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var debateBoxTitle: UILabel!
    
    var debate: Debate! {
        didSet {
            debateBoxImage.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: debate.imageURL))
            debateBoxTitle.text = debate.name
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit(){
        let bundle = Bundle(for: LogoraApp.self) // I'm not using "Bundle.main" because it is a framework.
        bundle.loadNibNamed("DebateBoxView", owner: self, options: nil)
        debateBoxView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(debateBoxView)
        debateBoxView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        debateBoxView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        debateBoxView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        debateBoxView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

In my tableViewCell :

```
import UIKit

class DebateBox: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var debateBoxView: DebateBoxView!
}
```

And then in the tableView itself:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = searchResultsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchDebateBox", for: indexPath) as! DebateBox
        cell.debateBoxView.debate = debateSearchResults[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: did you maybe forget to put an identifier of the xib?

Comment: Do you have some errors in the console ?

Comment: I have no errors in console. @stackich where should I put an identifier in the xib ? I linked it with my UIView as a file owner of the xib and added an outlet.

Comment: Open xib and then open the attributes inspector, you will see `identifier` as the first field.

Comment: Nope, only have Simulated metrics and View sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. And the problem was that my constraints for my xib file where not detailed enough so it was not displaying in the UI. Here is my code for initializing the nib if somebody passes by:

```
override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit(){
        let bundle = Bundle(for: Self.self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
        nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)

        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar to this... try registering the cell in viewDidLoad.

searchResultsTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DebateBox", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "searchDebateBox")